# Why is this ngif not working properly with a boolean?

Tags: angular

I've come across an odd issue when using an ngif statement in my template.  The statement is supposed to display render a "Valid" icon when the condition is true.  So some reason though it wont render anything at all.  I have confirmed the condition is coming through as true as when I output the condition to the console, it shows as true or false depending on the date correctly.  Am I doing something wrong here?

detail.component.html

```
<br> Current Status: <span class="badge badge-success" *ngIf="isActive">Active</span>
```

detail.component.ts

```
let isActive = false;
const validToDate = new Date(this.client.validTo);
if (validToDate.getTime() >= this.currentDate.getTime()) {
  isActive = true;
}
console.log(isActive);
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You are declaring variable in local scope and trying to access outside that function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare variable inside function. It will not be available outside that function.Declare variable outside function so that you can access that variable in template

**Try this**

**component.ts**

```ts
export class AppComponent{ 
    isActive = false;
    constructor(){
        const validToDate = new Date(this.client.validTo);
        if (validToDate.getTime() >= this.currentDate.getTime()) {
          this.isActive = true;
        }
        console.log(this.isActive);
    }
}
```

**component.html**

```html
<br> Current Status: <span class="badge badge-success" *ngIf="isActive">Active</span>
```

Comment: This was it.  Thanks for spotting that, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`ngIf` works off of a class property. You need to declare the `isActive` as the component class property:

```
export class MyComponent {
    isActive = false;        
    doSomething() {
        const validToDate = new Date(this.client.validTo);
        if (validToDate.getTime() >= this.currentDate.getTime()) {
            this.isActive = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget the `false` condition!

Comment: That was the issue - the variable was declared inside the function.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

or me this wasn't working because I'd missed the inclusion of some declarations under @NgModule in app.module.ts:

When running through https://angular.io/start/start-data

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopBarComponent,
    ProductListComponent,
    ProductAlertsComponent,
    ProductDetailsComponent,
    CartComponent,
    ShippingComponent
  ],
```